# Get variable value from another void

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, call, void

I just started programming in XCode and I need your help.
I have two voids; in the first void I create a NSString, and in the second void I need the value of that string, but i don't know how to obtain that value.

This is a shortend version of my .h file

```
//.h file
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self ActionOne];
}

-(IBAction)ButtonClick (id):sender
{
  [self ActionTwo];
}

    -(void)ActionOne
    {
      NSString *VarString = @"hello";
    }

    -(void)ActionTwo
    {
      NSLog (@"%@", VarString);
    }
```

My problem is that NSLog's output is 'null', I hope someone can help me

Comment: These are "methods", not "voids".  `void` is the return type of the method.  You will confuse people if you call your methods by the return type. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a *local variable* in `ActionOne`.  It only lives as long as the method is running.  For persistent storage, you need an *ivar* (that's a term used in Objective-C to mean an "instance variable", which is a variable for which there is a separate copy for each object that is an instance of a class).  The easiest way to do this is to declare a property, which will create an ivar and methods to access it for reading and writing.  In your .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *varString;

// ... method declarations, etc

@end
```

And then in your .m file:

```
-(void)actionOne
{
    self.varString = @"hello";
}

-(void)actionTwo
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.varString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already knew that I needed to declare the property,
But I didn't know that I needed to replace
'NSString *VarString = @"hello";'
With ' self.varString = @"hello";' Thanks!